# Why does 'this' and 'prototype' behave differently on constructor vs instance?

Tags: javascript, constructor, this, prototype

I'm trying to understand why [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) behave differently in the constructor vs. the new instance.  In the following code Aircraft.range returns undefined.  I can't understand why it doesn't return 2,000 like the new instance.

```js
function Aircraft() {
    this.range = '2,000 Km';
}

let mustang = new Aircraft();

console.log('Aircraft.range ', Aircraft.range);
console.log('mustang.range ', mustang.range);
```

This attempt using prototype produces the same result.

```js
function Aircraft() {}

Aircraft.prototype.range = '2,000 Km';

let mustang = new Aircraft();

console.log(Aircraft.range);
console.log(mustang.range);
```

**** Update ****

I've read many articles on prototypes and instances but theory only goes so far.  This is a specific question used to work out the mechanics of these ideas.  The answers I received helped me understand this concept better than a dozen articles talking about theory.  I'm sure that these answers will help other people trying to learn the fundamentals of Javascript.

Comment: I really don't know why you would expect them to behave the same, instances and constructors are completely different things.

Comment: No kidding.  They're different?  It's all clear now.

Comment: Yes, they are different. If you said `x.size = function() { }` and then asked why `y.size` is undefined, that would be the same as the question you've asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: It only looks the same because you used a scalar. Consider: `function Foo(){ this.notShared = { a: 1 } }; Foo.prototype.shared = { b: 2 }; var foo = new Foo(); var bar = new Foo(); bar.shared.b = 3; console.log(foo.shared.b); // 3!!`. The `notShared` of each instance can be safely mutated, but if you have a mutable object on the prototype all the instances point to the same object.

Comment: @JaredSmith that concept I understand.  It's basically like opening two different windows to the same room.  Alter something in the room and it doesn't matter which window you're looking through you see the same alteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple explanation for all three cases:

- `this.range` means that `range` is a property of the created instance only.
- `Aircraft.prototype.range` means that `range` is a property of all instances you'll create because it's defined in the constructor's prototype.
- `Aircraft.range` means that  `range` is a property of the constructor (because functions are objects) and is not related to instances. Instances can only access that property by using `this.constructor.range`.

Comment: Ok interesting I can follow that.  But in no case is `range` a property of the constructor?

Comment: and neither define `Aircraft.range` (oops, the edit explained that) - if you want `Aircraft.range` to be "something" you have to set `Aircraft.range` to "something"

Comment: @Angle Politis ok that makes sense!  Thank you for explaining all three examples.  I wouldn't have understood without being able to compare all 3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something that really helped me understand this was understanding exactly what the `new` keyword does.

`new Aircraft` means:

1. create an object ("`{}`")
2. call the `Aircraft` function with the object as `this` (setting `.range` on that object to `"2,000 Km"`
3. set the prototype of that object to `Aircraft.prototype`

You could sort of implement it yourself like this:

```
function _new ( constructor ) {
    var instance = {};
    constructor.call( instance );
    instance.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return instance;
}
```

`_new( Aircraft )` is roughly equivalent to `new Aircraft()`.

Comment: It might sound simple but knowing that `new` means create `{ }` does help cement that in my brain.